# TortoiseSVN's overlay icon on folder is not 'modified' but 'normal' when file inside that folder is modified

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows-10

Icon is properly shown as 'modified' on file. On folder, inside which is that modified file, icon is 'normal'. Can anybody tell me what setting should I change in order to see 'modified' icon on modified folder?

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.9.4, Build 27285 - 64 Bit on Windows 10.

Note: In TortoiseSVN's settings, under Icon Overlays I already set status cache on 'Shell' and checked removable, network and fixed driver types. Also in win registry editor Tortoise's overlay identifiers are first.

Answer (score 2):

The folder was on desktop, and desktop is on shared disk. So I moved the folder on local disk and set status cache on 'Default', since when on 'Shell' the icon overlays are not recursive. Now it works as it should.